# Is it possible to group a query by each n minutes using read only access

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query where I can extract data and present it in a line diagram. I'm having trouble with the presentation as I would like group the result by every n minutes (5 in my example).

I would like my result set to include one row for each n:th minute even if there are not hits on a given n:th minute.

Another problem I'm facing is working on a connection where I only have read_only rights.

I've tried reading various recommendations on how to solve my issue, but most seem to recommend including either an additional timetable with each n:th minute as a table to join onto, or including a server side function. 
I'm unable to utilize these particular suggestions as I can't add functions and/or tables to the db.

Thank you very much in advance, for any suggestions on how to solve this issue.
 - Jonas

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, P.[TIME])/5 * 5,0), 120),
    SUM(P.[AMOUNT]),
    P.[Q],
FROM
(SELECT
    MessageType AS [Q],
    Handled AS [TIME],
    count(Handled) AS [AMOUNT]
FROM dbo.CosMessage
WHERE MessageType IN('Z03', 'Z04', 'Z05')
GROUP BY Handled, MessageType) AS P
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, P.[TIME])/5 * 5,0), P.[Q]
```

My current result set looks like this:

```
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z03
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z04
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z05
2019-07-02 10:50    7   Z03
2019-07-02 10:50    24  Z04
2019-07-02 10:50    2   Z05
2019-07-02 11:20    1   Z05
```

I would like my result ordered as this:

```
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z03
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z04
2019-07-02 10:45    2   Z05
2019-07-02 10:50    7   Z03
2019-07-02 10:50    24  Z04
2019-07-02 10:50    2   Z05
2019-07-02 10:55    0   Z03
2019-07-02 10:55    0   Z04
2019-07-02 10:55    0   Z05
…       
2019-07-02 11:20    0   Z03
2019-07-02 11:20    0   Z04
2019-07-02 11:20    1   Z05
```

Comment: So you want a time that is a round five minutes for z03 to z05, 36 rows per hour, every hour for the entire date range? Yea it can be done on a read only connection; you basically generate a time series mathematically and cross join it with your z0x, then left join your data onto it. Someone will be along to demonstrate shortly - im on a cellphone

Comment: Yes, this would be the ideal. I'll try looking around for how to generate time series and joining my query onto that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment we need to generate some rows of dates. It's far better to use a numbers table for this but I'm assuming you don't have one:

```
WITH dg (d) AS (

  SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2019-07-02 10:45:00', 120) AS d
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(minute, 5, a.d) as d
  FROM   dg a
  WHERE  a.d < CONVERT(datetime, '2019-07-02 11:20:01', 120)
)
```

Selecting from this will generate a list of dates 5 minutes apart between 1045 and 1120

Next we need to cross join this with some values to get our Z numbers;

```
SELECT * FROM
  dg
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 'Z03' as z UNION ALL SELECT 'Z04' UNION ALL SELECT 'Z05') z
```

This will repeat every time thrice, matches with each different Z, so now we just left join our real data onto it:

```
SELECT dg.d, z.z, COUNT(m.MessageType) as c FROM
  dg
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 'Z03' as z UNION ALL SELECT 'Z04' UNION ALL SELECT 'Z05') z
  LEFT JOIN dbo.CosMessage m
  ON
    z.z = m.MessageType AND
    m.Handled >= dg.d AND
    m.Handled < DATEADD(minute, 5, dg.d)
GROUP BY
  dg.d, z.z
```

Your original query went to some effort to round the time to the nearest 5 minutes. We can avoid this by getting sqlserver to do the join based on the time range the actual time falls into - a time of 10:46 falls into the `10:45 to 10:45+5` range. Matching on the `z.z = m.messagetype` will restrict to only those z3 to z5. Finally because it is a left join if there is no matching record, the dg.d and the z.z have a vale but m.messagetype will be null, and count doesn't count nulls so will return a zero for those rows:

```
dg.d               z.z  m.handled         m.messagetype
2019-07-02 10:50   Z05  2019-07-02 10:51  Z05            --it will count as 2 when grouped
2019-07-02 10:50   Z05  2019-07-02 10:52  Z05            --it will count as 2 when grouped
2019-07-02 10:55   Z03  null              null           --it will count as 0 when grouped
```

See how the 10:51 and the 10:52 have been assigned to the 10:50 time slot. When we group on just dg.d and z.z these will count as 2 in that slot, and the null row will count as 0

To see the final query in more action, remove the `group by` and make it a `select *`

Don't forget that you'll need to assemble the WITH from the top and the SELECT from the bottom of this answer; you can't run the SELECT on its own because it needs the CTE I defined at the start, but I didn't repeat the WITH in the final query, for clarity

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help Caius. It functioned almost immediately as I tried it, and I've spent some time trying to read up and learn from your example, and trying out additional variations on my own.

I'm new to the site, and having this comment as my first experience humbles me. You really helped me out with a problem that I couldnt have solved on my own. Thanks yet again // Jonas

Comment: You're most welcome! If you're satisfied that a particular answer solves your problem, click the grey tick to the left of the top line of the answer, to mark is as the answer you accept. You can also up vote any number of answers you found helpful, including the answer you accepted as best for you, by clicking the up arrow above the number

Comment: I marked the checkmark. When I upvoted your post, the site prompted that I had too few reputation points of my own, for it to show up unfortunately. 

I hope to some day help someone else in the same friendly mannerism that you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but a little complicated. You should modify date before grouping. In your example you want every 5 min records. So change your last digit of minute to 0 or 5. You can achive this by modula as `DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, your_date) % 5) * -1, your_date)`. After this change, format that calculation as `FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, your_date) % 5) * -1, your_date), 'yyyyMMddhhmm')`. Now you can group by this value.

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, your_date) % 5) * -1, your_date), 'yyyyMMddhhmm'), COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEPART(MINUTE, your_date) % 5) * -1, your_date), 'yyyyMMddhhmm')
```